# How to show two column of database in one coloumn in admin controller in prestashop module

Tags: controller, prestashop

As you know in prestashop controller we can get information from database and show theme in atable by field_set for example

```
   $this->fields_list = array(
      'clerkfamily' => array(
          'title' => $this->l('family'),
          'havingFilter' => true,
          'callback' => 'printSender',
      ),
      'useremail' => array(
          'title' => $this->l('email'),
          'havingFilter' => true,
          'callback' => 'printSender',
      ),
```

);

So clerkfamily and useremail are name of columns in my database table but here I want to show theme in just one column what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->_select = 'CONCAT(a.`clerkfamily`, \'. \', a.`useremail`) `customField`';
$this->fields_list = array(
    'customField' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('family'),
        'havingFilter' => true,
        'callback' => 'printSender',
    ),
);
```